# Cannot get center align an image consistently across numerous monitors

Tags: css, image, header, squarespace

Trying to help a friend of mine with a Squarespace website and attempting to add an image in the header code.

I've tried aligning centrally but it doesn't seem to work. Only padding and margin pixels have any effect but then it's not consistent when using different sized monitors.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Current code below:

```
<a href="https://wwwmisscurrentcom.squarespace.com/about-1/"><img class=
"thumb-image loaded" data-image-dimensions="960x41" data-image-resolution=
"1500w" data-src=
"https://static.squarespace.com/static/53ce81e3e4b065e3be155770/53cfbd0ce4b056db8c5d3b42/53e4fdb9e4b036cda0551713/1407516127095/header-shipping.png?format=1000w"
id="yui_3_17_2_1_1407515470914_1223" src=
"https://static.squarespace.com/static/53ce81e3e4b065e3be155770/53cfbd0ce4b056db8c5d3b42/53e4fdb9e4b036cda0551713/1407516127095/header-shipping.png?format=1000w"
style="top: 114px; position: relative;margin-left: 150px;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question a few times, I think I know what you are asking. You can centre your image with `margin: 0 auto;`. The `auto` left and right margin will keep the block element (in this case, a `div`) dead centre horizontally across all resolutions and screen sizes.

[Have a jsBin example!](http://jsbin.com/pawuye/1/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x100" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    /* 
        shorthand margin = 
        top (0)
        right (auto) 
        bottom (0 - inherited from top) 
        left (auto - inherited from right); 
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it properly centered you will have to access the custom css and use media queries.  The problem with standard pixels and percentages in SquareSpace is that you may get it centered on your monitor but it will not always center on other hardware/devices.